# C ADT function pointer as parameter?

Tags: c, function-pointers, abstract-data-type

I have a function in an ADT:

```
Pgroup new_group(int size, void (*foo)(void *));
```

In my other class I have this function to send in:

```
void foo(Pstruc x);
```

x is a pointer to a struct. When I try to call new_group however, I receive an error "expected 'void (*)(void *)' but argument is of type 'void (*)(struct struc_ *)". This is how I've been calling it:

```
Pgroup group = new_group(num, &foo);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: What function call should I make to have it compile correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the argument to the correct type to get rid of the diagnostic:

```
Pgroup group = new_group(num, (void (*)(void *)) foo);
```

Note that this is not portable as C does not guarantee that the representation between different pointers is the same. The best would be to use types that match in their declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your original function from `void foo(Pstruc x);` to `void foo(void* x);`.

Or convert its type: `(void(*)(void*))foo`.

Comment: `(void(*)(void*))foo` is a Bad Idea - it'll work now, but it'll probably come back to bite you at some point in the distant future and you'll have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: (Although, as far as function pointer casting goes, that one is relatively tame compared to when people try to cast function pointers with different calling conventions or differently sized parameters)

Comment: So, it is better to have untyped header function declarations between modules for those tricky cases.